# Accessing MFC dialog elements from outside member class

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, static, dialog

I am trying to call a non static function of my MFC dialog class (which gets an edit box's value and returns it as a string) from outside the dialog class.

Namely, I have `Dlg.cpp` and `calc.cpp` and I want to call `getEditBoxContents()` from `calc.cpp`. I know that to call a non static function I should have an element of `Dlg` in `calc.cpp` in order to do `aDlg.getEditBoxContents()` however, doing `Dlg aDlg = Dlg()` and then doing `aDlg.getEditBoxContents()` gives me cryptic errors (I am sure this isn't the way I should be doing it anyway).

Can someone please point me in the right direction or give me another way of getting an edit box's contents from outside the dialog class?

---

Thanks to Nik, the solution that worked for me is:

In the non member class:

```
CEx3Dlg *pMainDlg = (CEx3Dlg *)AfxGetMainWnd();
pMainDlg->exp_ListBox.AddString("asd"); //Interact with GUI elements here.
```

Comment: The solution worked for you because you are coding a dialog-based application and wanted to get a pointer to the *main window* of your application. While it will work for others in that particular scenario, this isn't a panacea.

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with a dialog's GUI elements from outside. You could change them in the future (turn an EditBox to a listbox, change a check box by a list of radio controls...). Check [this article](http://www.flounder.com/dlgctl.htm) for a much better explanation, ways of doing it right, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling this wasn't the good practice way of doing it, but it worked for my purposes. I will look at your article for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in question is one line, so we can't really analyze it line by line... let's try something more "granular":

```
Dlg aDlg = Dlg()
```

So, here we declare a variable of type `Dlg` called `aDlg`. It's initialized using the default constructor. We then construct a *new* dialog (the `Dlg()` part on the right-hand side of the `=`) and assign that to our `aDlg` variable.

At this point, all we have is an instance of a Dlg object. The corresponding Windows dialog hasn't been created (since `DoModal` or `Create` haven't been called). So then we try calling `aDlg.getEditBoxContents()`. Presumably this member function attemps to get the contents of some edit box. But there's no edit box whose contents we can get.

Without knowing details about what you're trying to do, typically, you would want to have some code like this:

```
Dlg aDlg;
aDlg.DoModal(); /* create and display the dialog */
aDlg.getEditBoxContents();
```

Notice that `DoModal` creates a *modal* dialog which will block access to other windows in your program (this is an overgeneralization, but bear with me for a moment; the details aren't likely to make a difference to you in this case). So, the `aDlg.getEditBoxContents()` function won't be called until you click the close button, or the OK button or the cancel button on the dialog.

Without knowing more, it's hard to help, but I hope this gives you a place to start from.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that I presumably already have an instance of `Dlg` flying around somewhere which contains the edit box with the user's input in it. When I create a new `aDlg`, won't this give me access to a new edit box which the user hasn't interfaced with yet?

Comment: If you have an instance of `Dlg` out there, then you should use that. A new instance of `Dlg` won't give you access to that other one nor will it have an edit box until after you tell Windows to *create* the dialog using either `CDialog::Create` or `CDialog::DoModal`. Think of it like this: when you create an instance of `Dlg` you essentially have a box. You can look inside the box all you want, but unless you put something in it, the box will be empty. In this case, you put something in it by creating the *underlying* Windows dialog (which is distinct from the `Dlg` instance).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd like to use the instance that already exists. The problem is that I can't find the instance of the dialog box... I know this sounds ridiculous, but the auto generated code appears to instantiate the dialog in a nonstandard way. I can't find it! (I've added the `OnInitDialog()` code to my question in case that helps.)

Comment: The framework and the autogenerated code don't instantiate dialogs, except the main dialog of a dialog based app. Is that the dialog you're trying to access?

Comment: Yes, I only have one dialog in my dialog based app. In the case that the auto code doesn't instantiate the dialog, is there any hope to access a dialog's edit box from outside the dialog class? I have tried getters and setters, but I keep getting errors based on the fact that I cannot call static methods from non static methods.

Comment: Ah - if you look at your `InitInstance` class, you'll see it instantiated. try `CEx3Dlg *pMainDlg = (CEx3Dlg *)AfxGetMainWnd()` and you'll get a pointer to that dialog.

Comment: Great! and now I do `CEx3Dlg *pMainDlg = (CEx3Dlg *)AfxGetMainWnd();
 pMainDlg->exp_ListBox.AddString("whatever");`